# Camera view(UIImagePickerController) show different orientation for different ios devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I am working in `cocos2d-iphone` and try to make Augmented Reality game. Firstly I followed [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/3997/augmented-reality-tutorial-for-ios) But I face a problem.

My sample Code is:

```
#product.h

@interface Product : CCNode <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{
    UIView *overlay;
    UIImagePickerController *cameraUI;
}

+(CCScene *) scene;
-(void)loadCameraView;

@end
```

then

## product.m

```
#define CAMERA_TRANSFORM  1.24299
-(void)loadCameraView
{
    // prepare the overlay view and add it to the window
    overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    overlay.opaque = NO;
    overlay.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    
    cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    cameraUI.showsCameraControls = NO;
    cameraUI.toolbarHidden = YES;
    cameraUI.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    cameraUI.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    //cameraUI.shouldAutorotate = NO;
    cameraUI.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(cameraUI.cameraViewTransform,
                                                          CAMERA_TRANSFORM, CAMERA_TRANSFORM);
    
    [overlay addSubview:[cameraUI view]];
    
    //[[CCDirector sharedDirector].view addSubview:overlay];
    [appDelegate.window addSubview:overlay];
    
    [CCDirector sharedDirector].view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [CCDirector sharedDirector].view.opaque = NO;
    
    //[appDelegate.navController.view setUserInteractionEnabled:false];
    [appDelegate.window bringSubviewToFront:appDelegate.navController.view];

}
```

This code works fine and load camera. But In various device like: `iPhone, iPad, iPod` and in different `ios version like: 7.0+, 8.0+, 9.0+`, camera view don't show same view in all devices, images are rotate -/+90 degree or more in same orientation of all devices.

So, what can I do for this issue that I can get same view?

Thanks

Comment: `camera view don't show same view in all devices` then hows it looks ? not getting question properly!

Comment: @KetanParmar:  In iPod 8.1 ios, when I load camera, camera view rotate -90 degree in Landscape orientation. Also I changed orientation, but always getting camera view rotate -90 degree according desired view